# packaging multi module maven project as one war

Tags: maven, web-deployment

I have a maven project and it has 3 modules core, admin, site.
admin and site are deployed as separate wars is it possible to have the whole thing packaged as one war?

Answer (score 0):

Without exactly knowing what classes you have and why this are 3 war modules some possibilities with Maven:

- Change to have only one war file, when you want to deploy them always as one why should they be separate modules?
- two modules only add some common resources for the last war file you can try to use a [war overlay](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/overlays.html).
- all three modules are separate war files have different content roots and should be separated at all cost. Create an ear module with the three war as dependency files and deploy the ear instead of a war file.